# Django search bar not getting to the right page

Tags: django, search, django-views, django-urls

My page has two ways to search services - one is a search bar and the other is clickable categories. The clickable category go to a page that has a category primary key attached to the view and the search bar results do not have a category pk attached. Thus, I created two separate views for this reason. The problem is that both views go to the same page the index.html. I want the search bar to go to the index_search.html. I think I set-up everything correctly, but it still does not work.

## Two views: search view, clickable items view:

```
#search form view
def service_finder(request):
    model = Service
    if ('s' in request.GET) and request.GET['s'].strip():
        query_string = request.GET['s']
        #get query is just searching for search terms in those fields of the query set
        entry_query = get_query(query_string,['description', 'tags', 'category'])
        table = Service.objects.filter(entry_query)[:60]
    return render(request, 'index_search.html', {'table': table})

 #clickable items view
 def servicesListView(request, category):
    model = Service
    table = Service.objects.filter(category=category)[:60]
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'table': table})
```

Here is the html template with both the search bar and clickable items:

```
    {% block content %}
<main class="category">

    {% include "search_form.html" %}

    <section class="category-list">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                {% for service in service_cat %}
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                     <a
                         href="{% url 'services_list' service.category %}"
                        {{ service.category }}
                    </a>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the search bar file or search_form.html:

```
    <div class="search-bar">
    <div class="container">
        <form method="get" action="{% url 'service_finder' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="input-group">
                <input name='s' value="{{request.GET.s}}"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search services" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="search">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" id="button-addon2">Go</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the urls for the two pages:

```
    path('services/<category>/', views.servicesListView, name='services_list'),
    path('services/find/', views.service_finder, name='service_finder'),
```

SOLVED:

Fixed this by switching the order of the urls.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the path `/services/find/` matches the previous pattern `/services/<category>/`. Just explaining the reason why the fix worked!